# python3 is not supporting gtk module

Tags: 14.04, gtk, python3, pygtk

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with python-2.7 and python-3 support. I am porting my python application from python-2.7 to python-3. I have `example.py` file which is importing below modules. and I `#!/usr/bin/python3` as python evn variable.

```
import gtk, gobject, time, sys, os, subprocess, signal 

**ImportError: No module named 'gtk'**
```

I am getting above error, when trying to run with python3.

Any idea what is missing here?

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

and replace `gtk` by `Gtk` in your code

or

```
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
```

see also : [Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial : Getting Started](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#simple-example)

Comment: I get an error: `AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'combo_box_new_text'`

Comment: ...and many many more errors.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [GObject introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection) based Python3 bindings for Gtk and friends:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
```

That needs the package `python3-gi` which is installed by default.

Some names have changed since PyGTK. The [Python GObject Introspection API Reference](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/) should help you to find the new names (and other changes).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I am not able to import many modules which been supported for 2.7 like gtk, gobject, time, sys, os, subprocess, signal. please share any document which has details  and helpful for porting py-2 to py-3.